# Share image error on an activity error

Tags: android, share, android-bitmap

I have an activity in my app with differents functions and clases, and of those works saving a bitmap and showing the dialog for sharing it. The bitmap is saved perfectly, but when I click the share button it FCs and gives me this error

```
Process: com.javierd.iifym, PID: 3562
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3918)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:871)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
                                                     at com.javierd.iifym.Utils.RewardsActivity$1.onClick(RewardsActivity.java:59)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is the activity:

```
    public class RewardsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void createDialog(final Bitmap bitmap, Context context){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
        dialog.getWindow();
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.goals_dialog);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ImageButton shareButton = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String imageFileName = saveBitmapAsImage(bitmap);;
                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/*");
                File media = new File(imageFileName);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
            }
        });
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        dialog.show();
    }

    private String saveBitmapAsImage(Bitmap imageBitmap){
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
        File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile().toString() + "/IIFYM");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        final File imageFileName = new File(myDir, "Reward_"+timeStamp+".jpg");
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFileName);
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return String.valueOf(imageFileName);
        }
    }
```

And that code is called from the main activity in this way:

```
final RewardsActivity rewardsActivity = new RewardsActivity();
rewardsActivity.createDialog(imageBitmap, context);
```

Could somebody help me please?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

#### Start Another Activity from An Activity

Do you know [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AnActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

#### How to use a dialog

A dialog is easily uesd: like this:

```
  // 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

  // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
  builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
   .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

 // 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
 AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

#### Custom Dialog

You can define a layout xml file.

```
  // custom dialog
  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
  dialog.setTitle("Title...");

   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ImageButton shareButton = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String imageFileName = saveBitmapAsImage(bitmap);;
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/*");
            File media = new File(imageFileName);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, but the ther activity doesn´t have any interface, i just need to use it´s functions.
The dialog works well, the problem is with `android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()` as you can read on the log

Comment: Your code is so strange ! Why do you put these code into an Activity?Is it different if you use a normal class?

Comment: some parts don't work on a class, and I need to access this code from differents activities

Answer (score 0):

Please go through my code ant try.

```
public class RewardsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // why not any layout?
}

public void createDialog(final Bitmap bitmap, Context context){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
    dialog.getWindow();
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.goals_dialog);
    dialog.show();

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ImageButton shareButton = (ImageButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String imageFileName = saveBitmapAsImage(bitmap);
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/*");
            File media = new File(imageFileName);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
        }
    });
    what this view doing here?  
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: No, still the same error.
The activity doesn´t have layout because its just used to create the dialog and use some other functions, and the imageView is an ImageView inside the dialog which shows the bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally it was easy, I just need to change `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));` to `context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));`